# IOS new update versioning code error meaning?

Tags: ios, phonegap

i keep on receiving this email after sometime i upload my IOS new version IPA to ITunes. But i don't know what does it mean anymore. My build version current is been increase to "0.0.27" due to upload keep on failing me. My CFBundleShortVersionString also increase to 97 due to some mistake in previous upload numbering. But i still can't seem to upload my IOS update to Itunes. Im doing phonegap cross-platform mobile application. First version is successful on 14 February 2018, and upload by appsuploader.  Any clue for what i miss will be appreciated.

Invalid Version - The build with the version “0.0.15” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number.

Invalid or Non-Increasing CFBundleShortVersionString - The value specified in the bundle's Info.plist file for the key CFBundleShortVersionString must be a string consisting of at most three dot-separated components, where each component is composed only of the digits 0 through 9. For example, any of the following are syntactically valid values for CFBundleShortVersionString: "1.0", "4.2.1", "3.46", "1.112.0"; whereas the following are all syntactically invalid: "1.4.0.0.0.0.5", "GX5", "3.4.2b6", "2.6GM", "1.0 (Gold)", "-3.6". Additionally, each updated version of the same application must have a CFBundleShortVersionString that increases relative to that of the previous version that was actually made available for sale on the iTunes Store. For example, if a previously-available version had a CFBundleShortVersionString of "1.4", then any of the following would be acceptable as the next update: "1.4.1", "1.4.332", "1.5"; but all of the following (though syntactically valid) would be unacceptable: "1.4", "1.3", "1.3.9", "0.9". For more information about the CFBundleShortVersionString key and the Info.plist file, see Apple's Runtime Configuration Guidelines at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/index.html

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Mark this as Resolve. It just an compilation conflict when selecting android and ios together. I compile the cross platform individually then can see the adobe phonegap build version is changing to latest. After that upload to ITunes and everything go smooth.